# iPhone how to debug customers phones

Tags: iphone, debugging

I've gotten a couple of bug reports from customers that I am unable to duplicate with my devices.  These aren't crashes hence no crash reports.  I'm trying to figure out what options I have to solve these bugs.  Keep in mind that these customers vary widely in their technological prowess and willingness to help out.

The best I can think of is making an ad-hoc build with logging enabled to a file in their documents directory, but then I need a way to get that file off their phone.

Specifically, Short of remote debugging (that would be great) I want to get a log file or some other diagnostics to see what is going on.

What options do I have?

EDIT:  Great information already given, but I am looking for something like 'writing log statements to a remote server', probably just for an ad-hoc (for debugging) build. So, basically, by looking at their log, hopefully, I can deduce where things go wrong.  I could build such a system, but wondering what is already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the ad-hoc build, you can send the app to your customers, so that they can install it in iTunes and from there on to their iPhones.

Dragging/dropping on iTunes your app will place it in the App folder.

As to retrieving your log file, you could implement copying of your log file back to itunes (like many apps do), so the customer could get it from there and send it back to you... or you could simply post the file through HTTP to a server of yours under the customer's control.

Answer (score 1):

AdHoc + TestFlightApp.com - extremely easy, powerful.

Comment: And it's free! Waiting for SDK. Thanks to this question, now I do know what is it for. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) is an option.